# UITableViewCell height: By adding items, increase height dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode10

I get below `json` response from webservice and depending on it, I have to add items to the UITableViewCell, like Map View, description UILabel view etc.

```
...
...
   "items": {
       "carousel": true,
       "description": true,
       "map": false,
       "options": true
   }
...
...
```

So, if the item says `true` I have to add and if it is `false` I would not add. Typically the items looks like below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to add these `UIViews (NIB files)` to `UITableView`'s `contentView`. But, definitely the `UITableView` height does not grow. 
I tried some geometry arithmetic but it does not work and I do not want to do that as it is not really that dynamic.

Can someone please tell how can I get `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` work for this?

Comment: Simply add a switch statement in the height for row at index path datasource method. If you would like me to present it as an answer feel free to ask.

Comment: I actually did the same with `switch`. But I am trying with Auto Dimensions for simplicity. Do you mind giving answer? Let me verify with my code.

Comment: There are few things you must do to make the auto dimension work: **1** Each cell must calculate its own height - with proper constraints. **2** Make sure you set the the table view `rowHeight` property to `automaticDimension` and give the `estimatedRowHeight` a proper value to prevent UI jumps